# Strong convexity and operator monotonicity with arbitrary norms

Tags: convex-analysis, monotone-operator-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be strongly convex with respect to a (not necessarily Euclidean) norm $\|\cdot\|$, so that
$$
f(y) \geq f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)+\frac{\mu}{2} \|y-x\|^2
$$
is satisfied for all $x,y$.
For the Euclidean norm, one could also write the equivalent condition
$$
(\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y))^T(x-y) \geq \mu\|x-y\|^2.
$$
Does a similar condition hold for strong convexity with respect to an arbitrary $\ell_p$ norm?

More specifically, I'm trying to prove that the inverse operator $(\nabla f)^{-1}$ is a function and is Lipschitz with $\frac{1}{\mu}$, as in the case with the Euclidean norm.
Is a similar result possible in the general case?

Comment: How do you define $(\nabla f)^{-1}$? The gradient of $f$ is a vector...

Comment: Norms on finite-dimensional spaces are equivalent, so you can get the inequality with any $l_p$ norm but with a different constant

Comment: You can write down your first inequality with the roles of $x$ and $y$ reversed. By adding this to your original first inequality, you get the second inequality with the same norm.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth While in general $(\nabla f)^{-1}$ is set valued, for strongly convex $f$ it can be shown to be a Lipschitz function. For the $\ell_2$ case for instance: https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/monotone_primer.pdf

Comment: @daw Just norm equivalence seems to give a poor (dimension dependent) constant, which is why I thought there could be a better result based on strong convexity.